# Скрыть цену в карточке товара или в каталоге Magento 2.1

Tags: magento

Здравствуйте!
Есть задача скрыть цену определенных товаров в карточке и в списке каталога. Ознакомился с devdocs и прочитал, что есть возможность в админке скрывать блоки и контейнеры через Layout Update XML. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с названиями блоков в шаблоне (где как и куда смотреть?). С командами понятно, это есть в devdocs по Магенто, а вот где раздобыть названия блоков... тут увы нужна помощь...
Заранее благодарю!
Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Имя блока выводящего стоимость продуктов как в листинге (списке продуктов категории) так и на странице продукта `product.price.render.default` который фактически подбирается по коду стоимости (вроде `final_price`) из пула всех возможных блоков для отображения цены с именем `render.product.prices`. По итогам моего небольшого изучения вашей проблемы, скрыть этот блок через лэйаут невозможно (для базовой темы), т.к. блоки требуют его обязательного наличия. Как следствие при попытке убрать блок из лэйаута:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

возникает фатальная ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in ...

Поэтому могу только посоветовать разобраться с плагинами, создать небольшой модуль, который добавит пару плагинов для блоков в которых отображается цена продукта и при выполнении указанных вами условий вернет просто пустую строку.

На вскидку это несколько кандидатов:

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::getProductPrice()
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::getProductPrice()
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::getProductPriceHtml()
```

В последнем блоке существует интересный метод `getCanShowProductPrice()` в котором присутствует проверка `return $product->getCanShowPrice() !== false;`, это так же один из возможных вариантов решения вашей проблемы.

Ну или самое простое решение, это ручками модифицировать соответствующие темплейты (актуально если вы делаете это для конкретного магазина, а не в рамках какого-нибудь модуля, который планируете распространять).

Comment: Спасибо! Есть над чем подумать.

Comment: @AndreyKolomoets Пожалуйста, если понадобится что-нибудь уточнить, спрашивайте, не стесняйтесь - я постараюсь помочь.